# How do i list all existing revisions of a SVN Repository in c# using SharpSvn

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I want to get a list of all revisions from a given Svn repository.
But i am pretty new to SharpSvn and Svn in general.
Is there an easy way to get this list?

If this question has already been answered, i would apreciate it if you linked the question.

Comment: You should add your "answer" to the question to show what you have tried so far. In general, `svn log` is the right choice for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this be an adequate answer?

```cs
SvnTarget target = SvnTarget.FromUri(Path);
Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logEventArgs;
List<Int64> revisionNumbersList = new List<Int64>;
SvnLogArgs logArgs = new SvnLogArgs();
DPISVN_CLNT.GetLog(path, logArgs, out logEventArgs);

Int64 latestRev = logEventArgs[0].Revision;
foreach(var arg in logEventArgs)
{
    revisionNumbersList.Add(arg.Revision)
}
```